# Trying to open a simple JSP file produces HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

Following my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282231/jsp-page-wont-move-the-another-page-after-user-enters-the-input), I've removed all my source files into a package called `model` , and now the project refuses to load while executing `http://localhost:8080/MyFirstServlet`.

I suspect the culprit is `web.xml` , here's the file :

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyFirstServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
   <description></description>
   <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
   <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>model.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/model/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282231/jsp-page-wont-move-the-another-page-after-user-enters-the-input/11283006#11283006
```

**this is index.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
    pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="model/LoginServlet" method="POST">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" size="20"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

This is the hierarchy of the project :

[image: hierarchy]

When I execute `http://localhost:8080/MyFirstServlet` and reach here :

[image]

I enter `first` and `second` into the text fields and then get this :

[image]

I've tried to fix it but nothing did , so I'd appreciate any advice , thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You form action should be

```
<form action="model/LoginServlet" />
```

and your Login servlet should define the package correctly.

```
package model;
```

Also your web.xml must declare this servlet class through fully qualified name

```
model.LoginServlet
```

Your servlet must extend HttpServlet.

If you make sure that all of the above are in place correctly and it still doesn't work. Then, You may need to check your build path settings in eclipse for this project.

Answer (score 1):

```
<servlet>
   <description></description>
   <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
   <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>model.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
```

You missed the package for the servlet-class.

Comment: If that still doesn't work you should have a new different stacktrace. Otherwise your new web.xml isn't deployed properly and its still refering to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace clearly shows what the error is , the ClassNotFoundException means the servlet Container is not able to find the specified Class in the web.xml .

Comment: I can see that , but how do I fix it ?

Comment: Please do cleanup of your Servlet , remove warnings / unnecessary referenced packages and then try to redeploy everything by stoping the tomcat and deploy and then start the server . Let me know if you still does not work .

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code in LoginServlet.java should be

```
package model;
```

Comment: Instead of action="model/LoginServlet" please try using action="/model/LoginServlet"